# What does Binomial return for non-integer arguments?

Tags: special-functions

Mathematica returns values for non-integer arguments passed to `Binomial`.
What is the definition of `Binomial` for such continuous arguments?

Example:

```
Binomial[9, 2]
36
Binomial[9, 2.3212312]
49.801
Binomial[9, 3]
84
```

Comment: The factorials are just replaced with gamma functions for noninteger arguments, since $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$.

Comment: Your question is not clear: are you asking what is the *definition* of `Binomial` for non-integer arguments?  Or are you asking *how this value is computed*?  The definition is in the documentation under details.  I don't know how it's computed, but it's probably not directly using the formula in terms of $\Gamma$ functions as that would result in the ratio of very large numbers.

Comment: I agree @Szabolcs, my question wasn't very clear. I'm satisfied by knowing that the Gamma function is used for non-integer input as pointed out by both J.M. and as stated in the documentation -- I honestly didn't read the documentation carefully enough.

Comment: @Name I made the question unambiguous.  Please review the edit.

Comment: @Szabolcs, "...it's probably not directly using the formula in terms of $\Gamma$ functions...", yes, likely combinations of `LogGamma[]` are used before exponentiating.

Comment: @Szabolcs cheers for the edit and answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica defines [`Binomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Binomial.html) for non-integer inputs as follows:

$$
\binom{n}{m} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(n-m+1)}
$$

You'll find this under the *Details* section on the documentation page of `Binomial`.